# Why did the Rambam leave out Beis Din's obligation to enforce mitzvos

Tags: halacha, rambam, mitzvah, beit-din-court

The Gemarra in [Kesubos 86a](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.86a.10?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [Chullin 132b](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.132b.9?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) teaches the following:

> במצות עשה כגון שאומרין לו עשה סוכה ואינו עושה לולב ואינו עושה מכין אותו עד שתצא נפשו
>
> With regard to positive mitzvot, for example, if the court says to someone: Perform the mitzva of the sukka, and he does not do so, or: Perform the mitzva of the palm branch, and he does not do so, the court strikes him an unlimited number of times, even until his soul departs, in order to force him to perform the mitzva.

The Rambam brings this idea in his commentary to [Kesubos 4:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Ketubot.4.6?lang=bi&p2=Rambam_on_Mishnah_Ketubot.4.6&lang2=bi)

> ומן הידוע שיש לו לדיין לכפות בני אדם על נתינת הצדקה לפי שהיא מכלל מצות עשה שהיה מן החיוב להלקות האדם עד שיעשה מצוה זאת שיש לו לעשותה באותו זמן או ימות וזה היה עיקר בכל מצות עשה

He also brings this in his introduction to [Sefer HaMitzvos](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaMitzvot%2C_Introduction_to_the_counting_of_the_Mitzvot?lang=bi).

> אמנם מצות עשה בכללם כל מצוה מהם כשתתחייב עשייתה יש לנו שנלקה הנמנע מלעשותה עד שימות או יעשה אותה

However, I've seen quoted that he doesn't bring this anywhere in his Mishneh Torah. Why is this so? One answer I saw is from Even HaEzel (Kriyas Shema 4:10), but I was wondering if there are any other explanations given.

Comment: I answered it in your latest question - it's educational and not Halachic.